# How to call a class from another in th same package shows an error how to fix it in java?

Tags: java, class, object, compilation, package

How to call a class from another in th same package shows an error how to fix it?

i have three classes

FirstPack.java

SecondPack.java

Main.java

Here is my FirstPack.java

```
    //FirstPack.java
        package mypack.in;

        public class FirstPack
        {

        public void fun()
        {
            try
            {
            System.out.println("First Package");
            }

            catch(Exception ae)
            {
            }

        }
        }
```

Here is my SecondPack.java

```
    //SecondPack.java
        package mypack.in;

        public class SecondPack
        {
        public void fun()
        {
            FirstPack f=new FirstPack();
            f.fun();

            try
            {
            System.out.println("Second Package");
            }
            catch(Exception ae)
            {
            }
        }

        }
```

Here is my Main.java

```
          //Main.java
           import java.lang.*;
           import mypack.in.*;
            class Main
            {

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            try
            {
            //FirstPack obj_fp=new FirstPack();
            //obj_fp.fun();
            SecondPack obj_sp=new SecondPack();
            obj_sp.fun();

            }
            catch(Exception ae)
            {
            }
        }

        }
```

On compiling Firstpack.java ie javac FirstPack.java - no problem

On compiling SecondPack.java ie javac SecondPack.java- Error ....

```
    C:\JAVASAMPLE\Package\Three\mypack\in>javac SecondPack.java
    SecondPack.java:7: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class FirstPack
    location: class mypack.in.SecondPack
            FirstPack f=new FirstPack();
            ^
    SecondPack.java:7: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class FirstPack
    location: class mypack.in.SecondPack
            FirstPack f=new FirstPack();
                    ^
    2 errors
```

And, on compiling Main.java ie javac Main.java - no problem

Package - mypack.in FirstPack.java  and SecondPack.java Outside mypack.in Main.java Sir if without package yes it workinf but with pakage it didnt working I am not using any IDEs

Comment: try javac -cp . SecondPack.java where cp stands for classpath and . refers to the current directory where in the class file of FirstPack is present

Comment: You're also going to need a constructor in FirstPack

Comment: @NonSecwitter no there will be a default constructor put by java during compilation

Comment: Also, why are you catching exceptions for `System.out.println()`?

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]**

Note, you should not be compiling each class independently. The Java compiler is designed to compile each class as it encounters the first instance of it in your source file. Compile your Main.java from the root directory, and you won't have any errors.

**[/EDIT]**

**[SECOND EDIT]**

I believe this is all happening because the `javac` compiler begins looking for classes in the current directory and then searches through sub-directories. Since `FirstPack` is part of the `mypack.in` package, it needs to be in a folder `./mypack/in/` beginning from the current directory (the directory you execute the compiler from. Basically, your compiler knows that `FirstPack` is actually `mypack.in.FirstPack` and will begin looking for `./mypack/in/FirstPack` from wherever the file you are trying to compile is residing.

http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

**[/SECOND EDIT]**

Although it is throwing an error on compilation, this program is executing properly for me. Ensure that `Main.class` is in the root directory, and that `FirstPack` and `SecondPack` are in %root%\mypack\in

I can't tell you exactly why all of this is the way it is, but I know it's working this way.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this:

```
///**Import the Package

import mypack.in.FirstPack;
```